# indeterminate forme $0\cdot\infty$

Tags: real-analysis

How to prove that $\lim\limits_{u\to-\infty} u^n \exp(u)=0$ ?

I try to put $u=-t$, $t>0$ 
then:
$$\lim\limits_{u\to-\infty} u^n \exp(u)=\lim\limits_{t\to+\infty}(-1)^n t^n \exp(-t)=\lim\limits_{t\to+\infty}\exp(\ln(t^m)-t)$$

is also an indeterminate form.

What is the idea ?

Comment: Apply L'Hopital's Rule to $\frac {(-u)^{n}} {e^{-u}}$ $ n$ times.

Answer (score 1):

For limits with exponential functions it can often be easier to use $\exp(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(\frac{x^n}{n!}) \geqslant \frac{x^N}{N!}$ , $\forall x > 0 , N \in \mathbb{N}$

Then using $t=-x$ we consider the behaviour of $|t^n\exp(-t)|$ as $t\rightarrow\infty$.

$|t^n\exp(-t)| = |t^n(\exp(t))^{-1}| \leqslant \left|t^n\left(\frac{t^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}\right)^{-1}\right| = \left|\frac{(n+1)!}{t}\right| \rightarrow 0$ as $t \rightarrow \infty$

Comment: is there an other method please ?  @GoodThanks

Comment: I'm sure there are many other ways but I find this to be the most elementary approach because I would define $\exp: \mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ as the infinite sum (once convergence has been checked of course). As the comment to your original question says, you could of course use L'Hopital's Rule but then you should be familiar with its proof. Is there anything in my proof that you would like clarified?

Comment: I don't know that $\exp(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{n!}$

Comment: Have you been using the definition that $\exp$ is the unique function satisfying $\frac{d}{dx}(\exp(x)) = \exp(x)$ and $\exp(0) = 1$? If so then it is not too difficult that prove that this infinite sum converges to $\exp(x)$ using Taylor series. Either way it is useful to know these infinite sums for functions such as $\exp$, $\sin$, $\cos$ etc.